# VUE , sometimes i get undefined value on click function

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of elements, created on v-for and binded value to and id.
When i click, i use the value to do stuff.
The problem is sometimes value is "undefined". Some other times is not. If is "undefined" and i click on the above list item and then back to "undefined" one i get the correct value.
What's going on?   :key is assigned on uniques id  in data (index+1)

```
<template
            v-if="filteredContacts.length > 0 || searchToggle == true"
          >
            <li
              @click="selectContact($event)"
              v-for="(contact, index) in filteredContacts "
              :value="contact.id"
              :key="contact.id"
            >
              <div class="logo">
                <img :src="contact.avatar" alt="LOGO" />
              </div>
              <span class="contact-name">{{contact.name}}</span>
              <div class="last-message">
                Here will stay the last message
              </div>
            </li>
```

Above the v-for, under the funcion:

```
selectContact(event) {
  let value = event.target.value;
  console.log(value);
  this.contacts.forEach((e) => {
    if (e.id == value) {
      this.currentContact = e;
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you clarify your problem a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in `value` attribute in `li` element, in your case you should pass the id directly via parameters :

```
<template
            v-if="filteredContacts.length > 0 || searchToggle == true"
          >
            <li
            
                v-for="(contact, index) in filteredContacts "
                 @click="selectContact(contact.id)"
              :key="contact.id"
            >
              <div class="logo">
                <img :src="contact.avatar" alt="LOGO" />
              </div>
              <span class="contact-name">{{contact.name}}</span>
              <div class="last-message">
                Here will stay the last message
              </div>
            </li>
```

```
selectContact(id) {
   this.contacts.forEach((e) => {
    if (e.id == id) {
      this.currentContact = e;
    }
  });
},
```